# Populating pandas dataframe efficiently using a 2-D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a 2-D numpy array each row of which consists of three elements - ['dataframe_column_name', 'dataframe_index', 'value'].
Now, I tried populating the pandas dataframe using iloc double for loop but it is quite slow. Is there any faster way of doing this. I am a bit new to pandas, so apologies in case this is something very basic.
Here is the code snippet :

```
my_nparray = [['a', 1, 123], ['b', 1, 230], ['a', 2, 321]]
for r in range(my_nparray.shape[0]):
    [col, ind, value] = my_nparray[r]
    df.iloc[col][ind] = value
```

This takes a lot of time when my_nparray is large, is there any other way of doing this?

Initially assume that I can create this data frame :

```
  'a' 'b'
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
```

I want the output as :

```
  'a' 'b'
1 123 230
2 321 NaN
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(my_array)`. You can also pass the `columns` parameter to name the columns at the same time. There is no need for any loop.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, I want my dataframe column as the first element of nparray, dataframe index as second element of my array, and the value at that index & column as the third element of the array.

Comment: Your edit has changed the requirement quite substantially. So now you may need to have `NaN` because you don't have values for all cells?

Comment: Apologies if the initial explanation was confusing, yes but the NaN problem I have solved using this :
pd.DataFrame(index=list_1, columns=list_2)
I have all possible values of indices/columns in lists, so I can first form this NaN dataframe and then proceed to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_nparray, index=1).pivot(columns=0)

       2
0      a      b
1
1  123.0  230.0
2  321.0    NaN
```

This specifies that the index uses field `1` from your array and pivot uses Series `0` for the columns.

Then we can reset the MultiIndex on the columns and the index:

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(None)
df.columns.name = None
df.index.name = None

       a      b
1  123.0  230.0
2  321.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_nparray).pivot(1,0,2).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
       a      b
1  123.0  230.0
2  321.0    NaN
```